# How do I update a property on UIView, using a pop-out view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a stroke width pop out menu to a simple drawing app using core graphics in Swift. How do I set the StrokeWidthViewController to update the strokeWidth property on DrawView.swift (UIView)?

I know how to pass data between view controllers, but I've never passed data to a UIView, using a view controller.  I don't need any code at this point, just a general explanation of what to do.

I'm happy to post my code if it will help with an explanation.

Thanks in advance.

[image: sotryboard layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it with views like you do it with view controllers. To pass data to a view you should define public property on this view and use custom setter. To pass data back you can use delegation.